# Pass Nokogiri object to ERB page, and then back to post

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nokogiri

This is in Sinatra.  In my 'get', I create an instance variable which is a nokogiri object, created from an external xml file.  I go to an erb file and parse through that nokogiri object in order to do the page layout.  In my post method, I need access to that same nokogiri object (I may return to post numerous times and may modify the nokogiri object).  The way I've been doing this is to set a hidden variable in the erb page, like this:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value= '<%= @test %>' >
```

Then in my post, I create a nokogiri object from that variable like this:

```
   @test = Nokogiri::XML(params["test"])
```

This seemed clunky, but I'm not experienced in this stuff.  Anyway, everything worked fine, except that somewhere along the line, my embedded quotes in the xml get mangled.  For example, node in my file starts like this:

```
<property name="blah" value='{"name:foo"}'> </property>
```

And when I do a puts in my post of params["test"], I get this:

```
<property name="blah" value="{"name:foo"}"> </property>
```

(single quotes became double quotes), and finally, after converting it back into a nokogiri object, with the following code:

```
@test = Nokogiri::XML(params["test"])
```

I get this:

```
<property name="blah" value="{"/>name:foo"}"&gt; </root>
```

Is there a better way to retain access to the object?  If not, is there a way to retain my embedded quotes ( I think setting the hidden variable in the erb file is where it gets mangeled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

1. Cache the Nokogiri documents in a constant (e.g. a hash or module), which live across requests (within the same server run; see below).
2. Send only the key to the hash in your form.
3. Use the key to get the document back out of the constant later on.

### Example

**package_32.xml**

```xml
<packages><kittens in_box="true">32</kittens></packages>
```

**cache_nokodocs.rb**

```ruby
require 'sinatra'
require 'nokogiri'

module NokoDocs
  @docs_by_file = {}
  def self.[](file)
    @docs_by_file[file] ||= Nokogiri::XML(IO.read(file))
  end
end

get "/xml/:doc" do
  @doc = params['doc']
  @xml = NokoDocs[@doc]
  <<-ENDHTML
  The XML starts with '#{@xml.root.name}'
  <form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="xml" value="#{@doc}">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
  </form>
  ENDHTML
end

post "/" do
  @xml = NokoDocs[params['xml']]
  @xml.to_s
end
```

**Using**

```
C:\>curl http://localhost:4567/xml/package_32.xml
 The XML starts with 'packages'
 <form method="post" action="/">
   <input type="hidden" name="xml" value="package_32.xml">
   <button type="submit">Go</button>
 </form>

# simulate post that the web browser does from the command line 
C:\>curl -d xml="package_32.xml" http://localhost:4567/ 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<packages>
  <kittens in_box="true">32</kittens>
</packages>
```

The first time any user requests a particular XML file, it will be loaded into the hash; subsequent requests for that file will fetch it from the hash directly, pre-parsed.

### Beware!

1. The documents will not be cached across multiple instances of the server (e.g. if you're behind a reverse proxy). They will also not be cached across server restarts. However, if these are static files on disk, the worst that will happen is that the particular server session will just have to re-create the Nokogiri document once before caching it.
2. Using the file name on disk and then letting the user post it back to you is probably a really, really dangerous thing to do. Instead, you might create a custom or random key when you load the document and use that. For example:

   ```ruby
   require 'digest'
   module NokoDocs
     @docs_by_file = {}
     def self.from_file(file)
       key = Digest::SHA1( file + rand(100) )
       [
         @docs_by_file[key] ||= Nokogiri::XML(IO.read(file)),
         key
       ]
     end
     def self.from_key(key)
       @docs_by_file[key]
     end
   end

   get "/xml/:doc" do
     @xml, @key = NokoDocs.from_file params['doc']
     ...
     "<input type="hidden" name="key" value="#{@key}">"
     ...
   end

   post "/" do
     @xml = NokoDocs.from_key params['key']
   end
   ```
3. This is a potential memory leak. Each unique document your users request is parsed as a big Nokogiri document and preserved *forever* (until you restart the server). You might want a system that records the last access time and have a timed job that periodically sweeps out items that haven't been accessed in a while.

Comment: Cool, thank you. It will take me awhile to digest this and try it, thanks for the in-depth explanation!

Comment: Hello, it has been a few months, but I'm back on the project.  I like your solution but have a question.  Does this -- "Cache the Nokogiri documents in a constant (e.g. a hash or module)" avoid collisions, if we have multiple users?  I am currently using a global (@@xml) to retain the object across requests, and we think that collisions are occurring.  Thanks.

Comment: @dt1000 You didn't 'accept' the answer I put effort into months ago. This disincentivizes me from helping you further. Additionally, you are not providing enough information. How can there be "collisions" for a file on disk? How are you generating your keys? How are you fetching them? What is the code you have now? Either edit your question with more details, or accept this answer and ask a new one.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry about that.  I'm speculating on the collisions.  I'm new to web development, so I don't know the practices.  I am using Sinatra, and in my main file (where all my gets and posts are, my main module maybe?) I currently have a class level variable (@@xml) nokogiri object, because I have to retain a copy of it that I can continue to modify over multiple posts.  However, if another user uses the app, isn't it possible that the class variable could get overwritten? Thanks

Comment: @dt1000 Yes, absolutely, all users would collide with that variable. You should use a session variable to store a short key string for the user and fetch that key to get the XML document when needed.